# Chrome Extension: Wait for sendMessage response before doing other function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback, async-await, messaging

I have two functions in my context menu extension. I have to click one in order to send a message to the content script and then I have to click the other one because the sendMessage functions sets the variables in my background script. What I'm trying to do is just make them one button and have the sendMessage function return first and then the other function can do it's thing because now the variables are set.
Here's what I mean:

**In background.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Send Message",
    contexts: ["all"],
    onclick: sendMessage
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Get All",
    contexts: ["all"],
    onclick: getAll
});

var title;
var link;
var bp;
var imgSrc;

function sendMessage() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            req: "request"
        }, function (response) {
            console.log("responded");
            title = response.title;
            link = response.link;
            bp = response.bp;
            imgSrc = response.imgSrc;
        });
    });
};

function getAll(info) {
    var el = document.createElement('textarea');
    var all =
        "<tr><td><img src=\"" + imgSrc + "\"></td>\n\
        <td><span class =\"productTitle\">" + title + "</span></td>\n\
        <td>" + bp.split("\n").slice(0, 5).map(i => '<span class="bulletPoints"><i class="fas fa-check" style="color: #5cb85c"></i> ' + i.substring(0, 90) + "...</span>").join("\n") + "</td>\n\
        <td>[boombox_button tag_type=\"a\" type=\"success\" url=\"" + info.pageUrl.substring(0, link.indexOf("dp") + 14) + "\" target=\"blank\"]Check Price[/boombox_button]</td></tr>";
    el.value = all;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

**In content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.req == "request")
        sendResponse({
            title: document.getElementById("productTitle").innerText,
            link: window.location.href,
            bp: document.getElementById("feature-bullets").innerText,
            imgSrc: document.getElementById("imgTagWrapperId").getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src.toString().replace(/_.*_/, '_SX250_')
        });
    return true;
});
```

I'm pretty new to Javascript and have been having a confusing time trying different things like callbacks, promises, setTimeout, not sure if I'm setting them up right but I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Add `getAll();` on a new line right after `imgSrc =` line.